# MakeAppx.exe crashes with Access Denied (error 5)

Tags: microsoft-edge

When trying to create an Appx file from a packaged Microsoft Edge extension, the MakeAppx.exe utility crashes with Access Denied (error 5).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Downloading a Windows 10 Fall Creators Update SDK to get a Windows 10 version of makeappx.exe fixed the problem for me. The Windows 8.1 version was crashing.

Download from: 
https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk

And then run the utility from:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.16299.0\x64\makeappx.exe"
```